# Permission to Anonymous user for Document of Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have site in sharpoint which is not available for Anonymous user.

I have created a document library and added Document in that. Now, I would like to show particular Document which is visible to anonymous and non-anonymous users.

Note : My site and Document library both are non-anonymous which is not visible to anonymous user. I only need to visible Document for anonymous user.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you must enable anonymous access for the Web Application.

Follow the guide below until the step where you select if you want to enable access for the "Entire Web Site" where you should set "Nothing". After that you will be able to set anonymous access on Item level.

http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/15/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-a-sharepoint-2013-site/